# How to record/verify method calls in unit tests without mocks?

Tags: unit-testing, immutability, elixir

How can I write expectations in my unit tests ?

Here is an example:

```
defmodule MyAPIModule do
  @url "http://example.com/path"

  def get_something(http_module \\ HTTPoison) do
    http_module.get!(@url, [], [])
  end
end
```

Here is my test:

```
defmodule MyAPIModuleTest do
  use ExUnit.Case

  test "Runs the get! method with no headers and no params" do
    MyAPIModule.get_something(HttpSpy)
    # 1) assert that get! was called
    # 2) assert [] == headers
    # 3) assert [] == params
    # 4) assert "http://example.com/path" == url
  end
end

defmodule HttpSpy do
  def get!(url, headers, params) do
    #
  end
end
```

My problem is immutability. I can't simply create a list in the HttpSpy module and record method calls with their params into that list.

So I tried to change HttpSpy this way:

```
defmodule HttpSpy do
  def start(listener) do
    spawn_link(__MODULE__, loop, [listener])
  end

  def loop(listener) do
    receive do

    end
  end

  def get!(url, headers, params) do

  end
end
```

and I changed the test to:

```
test "Runs the get! method with no headers and no params"
  spy = HttpSpy.start(self)
  MyAPIModule.get_something(HttpSpy)
  receive do
    {^spy, method_call} -> flunk("wrong method call")
    after 1000 -> flunk("timeout")
  end
end
```

but I'm stuck. HttpSpy.get! does not know the PID of the HttpSpy process spawned by the test.
Therefore HttpSpy.get! cannot send a message to the process which is waiting in the loop method.
Therefore the loop method will never send to the test (which I call listener) the function called and its params.

I realize that what I want is basically mock and expectations but I'd like to find the idiomatic way (= no mocks) to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Patrick gave a great answer and that would be my first approach. However, if you can't directly access the result returned by the spy, you can just send yourself a message:

```
# In the spy
send self(), :get_was_called

# In the test
assert_received :get_was_called
```

Comment: That's what I finally did. Works perfectly and is definitely more readable! I also believe these tests should not be the norm but reserved to the tests that test the boundaries of an app or library.

Answer (score 2):

You could just return the desired values from the fake `get!` function, extract them and then assert the results. You will implicitly know  that the correct function was called, because it returns the expected result.

```
defmodule FakeHttp do
  def get!(url, headers, params) do
    {:get!, url, headers, params}
  end
end

defmodule MyAPIModuleTest do
  use ExUnit.Case

  test "Runs the get! method with no headers and no params" do
    {:get!, url, headers, params} =
      MyAPIModule.get_something(FakeHttp)

    assert [] == headers
    assert [] == params
    assert "http://example.com/path" == url
  end
end
```

Anyway, I think it is not the most important thing to assert that a particular function was called. I think it is more useful to just do assertions on the externally visible result. That way, you can swap out the underlying implementations and your tests will still pass, as long as the new implementation produces the same result.